I'm sorry, Dave. I'm afraid I can't solve that
Preface
You guys know the drill here; standard connect-wall rules; what are the four categories of four in the below wall?
The title should clue you in to at least one of these!
Wall











RICHARD
TOBOR
LISA
JOHN


ERICH
WATSON
JOSHUA
BOX


HAL
PHOEBE
MAX
JOHNNY


RALPH
SIMON
JARVIS
HUEY




The title is a nod to a quote from:

 2001: SPACE ODYSSEY so I believe the first category is AI computers in movies -HAL (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HAL_9000), JARVIS (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J.A.R.V.I.S), MAX (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flight_of_the_Navigator), JOSHUA (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WarGames)

I think the second group is:

 names of robots in movies - JONNY (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short_Circuit_(1986_film), TOBOR (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tobor_the_Great), BOX (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logan%27s_Run), HUEY (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silent_Running)

Then up next we have:

 first names of the gang of four, authors who wrote Design Patterns: Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software RALPH, JOHN, RICHARD, ERICH (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns)

And then finally:

 real computers with names - PHOEBE (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phoebe_(computer), SIMON (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simon_(computer), LISA (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Lisa) and WATSON (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Watson)


You got it, great work!
